# Move tags from wiki excerpt out of question list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-nav

With the new navigation, if I am sorting by a single tag, the wiki excerpt is displayed (as it currently does). However, it also includes the tag and a lot of white space. Can we move this out of the question list or make it more compact? It adds unused space and pushes at least one question off the screen that can be seen other wise.

[image: Remove tag from display]

Under the current navigation, this information is off to the right, under the list of questions. It keeps the except more compact, yet still shows the tags being watched.

[image: Existing tag locations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important in to leave the tag in that position because it serves as a title and as a hook for the tag editor.

We do recognize that there's unnecessary duplication, but we are considering removing the tag from the side bar instead.

Comment: Just curious, how does it serve as a hook to the editor? The links to improve the wiki already exist in the current box. I'm not concerned with the duplication, I was more concerned about the larger tag boxes taking up screen real estate.

Comment: the "edit" link is made visible on hover, and the place occupied by the tags becomes a full tag editor on clicking it.