# Pin tags as tabs in the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

I thought it would be great to allow us to choose specific tags that will be available as tabs in the new navigation homepage (and even select one as the "home tab" as in the [last update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration?cb=1)).
That's similar to favorite tags, but even more "favorite".

[image: pin tags in the new navigation]

Comment: This. . .is actually a very good idea! I wonder if anything will stop it from happening.