# "Tab pinning" appears blank on tablet

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

"Tab pinning", as called in the featured topic  ([Improving our navigation, the next iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261307/210483)) appears blank on my tablet: I can see the boxes but no logo in it.

I can't really provide a screen shot... I hope it is OK.

**EDIT:** I went ahead and emulated the issue on my PC by using Firebug, it looks exactly like this:
[image]

I'm using the default browser on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Comment: just to clarify, you don't see the house icon on the button?

Comment: @m0sa Added an emulated-screenshot.