# Where are the “home tab pinning” settings stored?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, new-nav

I am currently participated in testing the new navigation. As per the Sklivvz post [Improving our navigation, the next iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration)

> Tab pinning! What tab you see on the home page is now an explicit
> choice instead of being autosaved.
>
> [image]

The new "Tab pinning" feature allows us to select our "home tab" and set it to one of the three options i.e. "new, popular and need answers". I initially thought it is a temporary setting i.e. until you logout but apparently it's not. I was in Chrome browser where my home tab was set to "popular" option. Then, upon login into Firefox browser I see that my home tab is currently set to "popular". And ditto goes for Safari browser too.

I looked under my "Profile & Settings" and "Preferences" but could not find anything about "home tab pinning" settings. So, where exactly are the “home tab pinning” settings stored under the new navigation? The only place I think is on the server side. Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That setting is saved server-side.

If you change the setting you'll see the following ajax call:

```
POST http://stackoverflow.com/home/tab-save
```

with the following payload, as content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
fkey=[your fkey]&tab=NeedAnswer
```

and, if all goes well, the following response

```
{"success":true,"message":"needanswer"}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the AJAX call info... Just cross checked in my Dev Tools... Perfect!!