# Make “and” tag search the default in the new nav, like it is in the old one

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, new-nav

In the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav), searching for `[tag1] [tag2]` defaults to [tag1] or [tag2].

I use “or” tag search maybe once a month, and it's inconsistent with the rest of the search syntax — if I search for `[tag1] is:q foo`, I get results that are questions containing “foo” and having the tag [tag1].

There's a way to switch to an “and” search: click on the little “all” button next to the “any” button. But that's cumbersome. The most useful feature should be the default.

Please make `[tag1] [tag2]` search for [tag1] AND [tag2], like it does in the old nav.

Comment: Would have upvoted a thousand times more. See also: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209909/how-to-combine-search-words-and-or-or

Answer (score 1):

The default composition is saved. You need to change it only once.

I've status-declined your request for the following reason: the default should be what benefits most inexperienced users. Setting the default to "and" would for example basically break filtering by "favorite" tags.

Note: there was a bug which meant that related tags always switched your default to or, which is now fixed. Clicking on a related tag behaves as before once your default is set.

Comment: I want `[foo] [bar]` to default to “and”, even if I happen to have made an “or” search previously. Like it is now. Switching based on what I did previously would be very confusing. Bringing in favorite tags is a red herring, there's no reason why they'd be routed to `[foo] [bar]` rather than `[foo] or [bar]`.

Comment: @Gilles let's say I am browsing "foo or bar", and I click a related tag "baz". what would the resulting combination be, given that we do not yet support complex queries?

Comment: Hmmm. Since you don't support it, you shouldn't show the related tags sidebar in that view.

Comment: If at least there was a way to explicitly type an “and” search, it would be less obnoxious (merely annoying). But I can explicitly type `[foo] or [bar]` (in the old search), whereas there's no way for me to say `[foo] and [bar]`.

Comment: @Gilles we do need to take a look at how the search box interacts with the new nav, but I fail to see what that has to do with related tags.

Comment: Why would the inexperienced users benefit from irrelevant search results? The normal words you write in the search box are searched by "and" (I sure hope), so how would anybody expect that typing in tags doesn't follow the same rule? That favorite tag filtering uses "or" internally makes sense, but this doesn't need to be connected to the default search setting?