# Reduce the hassle of switching between new-nav views

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-nav

With the new nav, on the front page or in a tag view, there are various dropdowns to select between selection and sorting options each with 2–4 options.

Clicking on a dropdown just to select between two options is too hard work. I find this especially annoying after a tag search, when I want to switch from “active” to “newest”. In the old nav, or when searching with criteria other than tags, it's a single click. Now, it's a click, move the mouse a little, click again.

[image: navigation bar]

There's plenty of white space here to expand on the UI a bit. For example, here, there's plenty of room for five radio buttons.

```
tags: ·all ·favorite •custom                                 sort: ·asked •active
```

Comment: To clarify, are you advocating subtabs for all sorts? Even when they are five?

Comment: @Sklivvz What do you mean by “they are five”? There may be supertabs where expanding all the boxes would be too cluttered, I didn't look at them all. At least in the example I show, there's plenty of room. If some are too cluttered, you will need to make a choice as to which ones need to be changed the most often. Changing the sorting order of search results between newest and active and votes (why don't I get votes here by the way?) is >50% so I really want it to be easy.