# Navigating from the front page to the mobile UI gives an error

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mobile-web, new-nav

Since the new navigation you can't switch from the home page to the mobile UI without getting an error: *Page not Found*.

> [image: page not found]

The reason is it doesn't understand `/new` in the URL. Removing that goes to the front page.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to http://meta.stackexchange.com
- Hit *mobile* in the footer
- Bang!

This is very annoying and confusing. Can you fix this please?

Comment: 99.999% that is by design, since the mobile version of the new nav is still not done. Though it's under "What's next?" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration) so expect it to work in 6-8 weeks/months. :)

Comment: Meh. It still shouldn't break basic and long-existing use of the application.

Comment: But it did from the very beginning (and most reports were silently ignored for long weeks), that's why I stopped using it.

Comment: This development process stinks...

Comment: True, I can understand the team using us as guinea pigs, had no problem when it was the profile page for example, but when it breaks the most basic usage like finding duplicates, I'm out of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now since the latest release. Navigation from the homepage to mobile to homepage works now.

This still doesn't work when selecting one of the tabs and then toggle to the mobile web UI, but I can understand that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile support is definitely on our list, but not until we have the desktop version out.